# How to make a only 1 window GUI in python?

Tags: python, user-interface, window

I am trying to make a GUI in python that only consists of 1 window. I think this is better explained with examples. If you have say the settings app open on the computer when you click an option a new window doesn't pop up, the original window changes the a new layout. Is there a way to do this without deleting everything in the window and then adding new stuff, and when going back doing the same process.

Comment: Which GUI framework are you using? What platfom?

Comment: I am planning to use Tkinter

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a QT based gui framework like PyQT or PySimpleGUI, you can accomplish this task using a Tab object. [Here is a link to a sample program with using Tabs in PySimpleGUI](https://www.pysimplegui.org/en/latest/Demos/#demo_tabs_simplepy)

PySimpleGUI is a really good option for getting your feet wet with GUI development in Python. You can get **a lot** done with very little code and learn about how GUI's work.

Comment:  Also https://pysimplegui.trinket.io/demo-programs#/layouts/swapping-window-layouts